# Laravel + react + inertia - components rendering twice

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-laravel

Hi so I have a problem with React components rendering twice in Laravel project. I made clean project, doing step by step from Laravel doc, installation (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#installation-via-composer) and starter kits (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze-installation).

The only thing that I added to code is `console.log(123)` to Login component. And in console it shows up twice, so I assume that this component rendering twice. I found on some webpage that strict mode from react sometimes forcing to render component twice, and I should do `npm run prod`, but it didnt change anything.

I'm adding code from app.js and Login.js but as I said its clean installation. Any ideas why this is happening?

**APP.JS**

```
require('./bootstrap');

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
    setup({ el, App, props }) {
        return render(<App {...props} />, el);
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

**LOGIN.JS**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Button from '@/Components/Button';
import Checkbox from '@/Components/Checkbox';
import Guest from '@/Layouts/Guest';
import Input from '@/Components/Input';
import Label from '@/Components/Label';
import ValidationErrors from '@/Components/ValidationErrors';
import { Head, Link, useForm } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';

export default function Login({ status, canResetPassword }) {
    const { data, setData, post, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({
        email: '',
        password: '',
        remember: '',
    });

    console.log(123);

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            reset('password');
        };
    }, []);

    const onHandleChange = (event) => {
        setData(event.target.name, event.target.type === 'checkbox' ? event.target.checked : event.target.value);
    };

    const submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        post(route('login'));
    };

    return (
        <Guest>
            <Head title="Log in" />

            {status && <div className="mb-4 font-medium text-sm text-green-600">{status}</div>}

            <ValidationErrors errors={errors} />

            <form onSubmit={submit}>
                <div>
                    <Label forInput="email" value="Email" />

                    <Input
                        type="text"
                        name="email"
                        value={data.email}
                        className="mt-1 block w-full"
                        autoComplete="username"
                        isFocused={true}
                        handleChange={onHandleChange}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="mt-4">
                    <Label forInput="password" value="Password" />

                    <Input
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        value={data.password}
                        className="mt-1 block w-full"
                        autoComplete="current-password"
                        handleChange={onHandleChange}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="block mt-4">
                    <label className="flex items-center">
                        <Checkbox name="remember" value={data.remember} handleChange={onHandleChange} />

                        <span className="ml-2 text-sm text-gray-600">Remember me</span>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div className="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
                    {canResetPassword && (
                        <Link
                            href={route('password.request')}
                            className="underline text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900"
                        >
                            Forgot your password?
                        </Link>
                    )}

                    <Button className="ml-4" processing={processing}>
                        Log in
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </Guest>
    );
}
```

**GUEST.JS (layout)**

```
import React from 'react';
import ApplicationLogo from '@/Components/ApplicationLogo';
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';

export default function Guest({ children }) {
    return (
        <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col sm:justify-center items-center pt-6 sm:pt-0 bg-gray-100">
            <div>
                <Link href="/">
                    <ApplicationLogo className="w-20 h-20 fill-current text-gray-500" />
                </Link>
            </div>

            <div className="w-full sm:max-w-md mt-6 px-6 py-4 bg-white shadow-md overflow-hidden sm:rounded-lg">
                {children}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: which component is the container of Login component?,the parent component may cause it to render twice

Comment: I added this file here in main post - it's Guest.js

Comment: can you just add a code where <Login/> is called?